# Calling a Cython Function form C Windowsx64

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython, public

after a long search without any results, i need some help.

I'm trying to call a Cython function form C.
I have the following Code:

**print.pyx**

```
cdef public int grail(int i, int a): # public function declaration
    return (i+a)
```

**modul.c**

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "print.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) {
    int a;

    Py_Initialize();
    initprint();
    a = grail(2,3);
    printf("%i\n", a);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

I try two ways to Compile and Link it, and i always fail by linking it.

First with Command Line:

```
cython print.pyx
gcc -LD:\Anaconda\libs -ID:\Anaconda\include -o print.exe print.c modul.c -lpython27 -g
```

Second with **setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension("print", ["print.pyx", "modul.c"])]
)
```

And then on Command Line:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

In both cases i got the same error:

```
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\modul.o:modul.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference t
o `__imp__grail'
```

Here are some additional information about my system:

Python 2.7.7 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (32-bit)

gcc (GCC) 4.7.0 20111219

Cython version 0.20.1

Windows 7 Enterprise x64

I hope someone know how i can solve the Problem, but already thank you very much for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd start with CFFI instead of writing this manually:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/03/09/python-ffi-with-ctypes-and-cffi

I'm not sure how well it works on Windows, though (it worked perfectly on Linux for me). It might work since CFFI project claims this about windows:

http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.8/#windows-64

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But thats not the right for me. I would like to you cython as interface.